# PWA share target - manifest is not refreshing

Tags: share, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

At first version of my pwa app I created manifest including share target

```
"share_target": {
    "action": "/product/new",
    "method": "GET",
    "params": {
      "title": "title",
      "text": "text",
      "url": "url"
    }
},
```

Everything was fine.
Now I decided to handle POST action instead of GET, so I changed share_target like this:

```
...
"share_target": {
    "action": "/product/share",
    "method": "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "params": {
      "title": "title",
      "text": "text",
      "url": "url"
    }
},
...
```

Changed method, action and added enctype. 
It seems like nothing changed. Sharing still calls old method /product/new (checked in backend logs, /product/share never called). Of course when I go directly to /manifest.json via browser, there is a new version of manifest.
I reinstalled my app, clear chrome cache. Nothing changed.
Do you have any idea how force it to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

In general to get `manifest.json` file updates your users have to uninstall and reinstall the app. Some sites are installed with [WebAPKs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks) and are the exception, they will generally check for updates every 24 hours.